# Extract 60 fps image from bag file

Tags: ros, rosbag, image-view, extract-images

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a bag file with a 60 fps camera image stream. I want to extract all the image frames. However, even if I specified _sec_per_frame to a very small value, I still got very low fps image files: there should be ~20k images for my 5min bag file, but now I only get ~2k images.

Here's the launch file I used:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbag" args="-d 2 /home/hangchu/MITLL/testTrackLoop_ii_2015-06-26-14-43-04.bag"/>
  <node name="extract" pkg="image_view" type="extract_images" respawn="false" cwd="node">
    <remap from="image" to="/camera/image_raw"/>
    <param name="filename_format" value="/home/hangchu/MITLL/images/frame%06i.jpg"/>
    <param name="_sec_per_frame" value="0.001"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212974/extract-60-fps-image-from-bag-file/) by [rosfuncoolstuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/22995/rosfuncoolstuff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe the problem is in your bag?

please, post the result of the command `rosbag info /home/hangchu/MITLL/testTrackLoop_ii_2015-06-26-14-43-04.bag` here, it will show how many image messages you have, than you can compare with the result of the extraction.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2015-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosfuncoolstuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/22995/rosfuncoolstuff/) on 2015-07-07**:
Thanks buddy! rosbag info shows 20321 image messages, but image_view image extract gave me ~2k images. I solved it with a "--rate 0.05" option when play the bag file.